# How To Set A Global Variable In Custom Vite Plugin in Vite Vue Project

Tags: plugins, vite

I need some advices that using to create a global variable / function from vite plugins. I've seen the docs from [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin) and no found my answers there.

I know how to create a vue plugin in native vue project like this

myPlugin.ts

```
import { App } from 'vue'
    
    const myPlugin = {
      install(app: App) {

        app.config.globalProperties.$myVariable = "My Variable"

      }
    }

export default myPlugin
```

and then we only need to use them in our main.ts file, then we can access $myVariable from all over the vue component on that project.

But here, is there any approach with vite plugins that can be able do the same things like vue plugin does above, because I'm using vue project with vite and using typescript...

Because I don't want to use vue plugin that use on main.ts instead I want to use a custom vite plugin that set in vite.config in order want to make them more organized in my project.

Or, the vite plugin is not the same with vue plugin for any reasons. If so,
then, I probably want to inject my vue plugin into vite plugins.

Thank you. Highly appreciated with the answers